# Postgresql 10.1 - two similar queries, 200 times difference

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Two queries. First is 200 times longest than second. Why?
PostgreSql 10.1. Metro and Sel - views on the same table.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         metro.id    AS id,
         metro.title AS name,
         metro.c1
       FROM metro
         LEFT JOIN sel
           ON metro.id = sel.metrosku
       WHERE sel.id IS NULL) t
WHERE t.c1 = 'продукты'
LIMIT 100;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH t AS (SELECT
             metro.id    AS id,
             metro.title AS name,
             metro.c1
           FROM metro
             LEFT JOIN sel
               ON metro.id = sel.metrosku
           WHERE sel.id IS NULL)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE t.c1 = 'продукты'
LIMIT 100;
```

Query 1:

```
"QUERY PLAN" Limit  (cost=0.00..34190.48 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=532.298..86938.359 rows=100 loops=1)
->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..34190.48 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=532.298..86938.274 rows=100 loops=1) Join Filter: (lower((original.info ->> 'SKU'::text)) = "substring"(((original_1.info -> 'Images'::text) ->> '0'::text), '/(\d+)'::text)) Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3555434 Filter: (lower((original_1.info ->> 'SKU'::text)) IS NULL) Rows Removed by Filter: 99
->  Seq Scan on original  (cost=0.00..17432.97 rows=1 width=1185) (actual time=0.038..2.962 rows=199 loops=1) Filter: (((competitor)::text = 'metrocc'::text) AND ((info ->> 'Type'::text) = 'Item'::text) AND (lower(((info -> 'Catalog'::text) ->> '0'::text)) = 'продукты'::text)) Rows Removed by Filter: 63
->  Seq Scan on original original_1  (cost=0.00..16754.80 rows=90 width=1185) (actual time=0.484..169.594 rows=17867 loops=199) Filter: (((competitor)::text = 'sel'::text) AND ((info ->> 'Type'::text) = 'Item'::text)) Rows Removed by Filter: 49950 Planning time: 0.471 ms Execution time: 86938.450 ms
```

Query 2:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
Limit  (cost=33521.79..33521.82 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=425.243..443.735 rows=100 loops=1)
CTE t
->  Hash Left Join  (cost=16755.92..33521.79 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=425.239..443.574 rows=140 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (lower((original.info ->> 'SKU'::text)) = "substring"(((original_1.info -> 'Images'::text) ->> '0'::text), '/(\d+)'::text))
Filter: (lower((original_1.info ->> 'SKU'::text)) IS NULL)
Rows Removed by Filter: 82
->  Seq Scan on original  (cost=0.00..16754.80 rows=144 width=1185) (actual time=0.022..7.077 rows=1638 loops=1)
Filter: (((competitor)::text = 'metrocc'::text) AND ((info ->> 'Type'::text) = 'Item'::text))
Rows Removed by Filter: 54
->  Hash  (cost=16754.80..16754.80 rows=90 width=1185) (actual time=424.723..424.723 rows=16215 loops=1)
Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 8 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 4066kB
->  Seq Scan on original original_1  (cost=0.00..16754.80 rows=90 width=1185) (actual time=0.612..175.330 rows=17867 loops=1)
Filter: (((competitor)::text = 'sel'::text) AND ((info ->> 'Type'::text) = 'Item'::text))
Rows Removed by Filter: 49950
->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=425.242..443.716 rows=100 loops=1)
Filter: (c1 = 'продукты'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 40
Planning time: 0.451 ms
Execution time: 449.512 ms
```

Comment: Let me guess probably some sort of [predicate pushdown](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/#top10) and itermediate materialization. Anyway `LIMIT` without explicit `ORDER BY` could return different result when executed many times.

Comment: @lad2025 But have you seen this behavior before? I thought they were  the same. I'm surprise to see this.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza At PostgreSQL no, but I saw many "odd" execution plans in Oracle/SQL Server.

Comment: In both cases you appear to have no valid statistics . (just compare expected<-->observed rowcounts) In the second case, you are saved by the hash joins (and the realtively small row counts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postgresql, if a cte's output is used, it is first materialized, then referred to. There is no predicate pushdown.

This is a known behaviour and documented here:

https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

and as others have pointed out, is evident in the explain itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's right on the `EXPLAIN PLAN` itself.

First query cost is `0.00..34190.48`. So the cost for returning the first rows is close to `0`. Since you only want the first `100` rows, it makes sense that it runs way faster than the second one.

Comment: But why? I was told cte is just another way to write subquery and db engine translate to subquery internally.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, that behaviour is valid in certain other database engines, but unfortunately not in postgresql. See the linked article in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Result of your `EXPLAIN PLAN`:
Query 1 (Sub query): Planning time: 0.471 ms Execution time: 86938.450 ms
Query 2 (CTE): Planning time: 0.451 ms Execution time: 449.512 ms

Based on your result, the CTE form is faster than the subquery form, in this case the planner is making poor optimization decisions.

You can try use `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE)` the detail might help.